# SFM to Blender Conversion

Tags: modeling, blend-files, file-format, conversion

I was wondering how to convert the files for sfm models, such as .vtx, .phy, .mdl, and .vvd into a Blender 2.8 compatible format.

Comment: i'd recommend looking it up more on their workshop page. there are guides and add ons there that are essential to importing and exporting SFM models

Answer (score 1):

You'll first need to decompile the .mdl file into an .smd file. Crowbar is an excellent tool to decompile mdl files, find it here: [Crowbar (Source Engine Modding Tool)](https://steamcommunity.com/groups/CrowbarTool)

---

After that, you can use the Blender source tools as 8foldhero suggested: [BlenderSourceTools](https://steamreview.org/BlenderSourceTools/)
Install it as an addon like usual, and you'll be able to import any smd file into Blender by going to `File > Import > Source Engine (.smd, .vta, .dmx, .qc)`, then choose the file from the dialog box. I recommend changing the Bone Append Mode to `Make New Armature`. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are some guides on the SFM workshop and wiki on how to do it specifically (Here is one from the wikia in particular https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Blender_Source_Tools_Help )

but the most essential think is the "Blender Source Tools" add-on. You will need to install this into blender, and then from that (File > Import > Source Engine Filetypes)

https://steamreview.org/BlenderSourceTools/